# Drupal 7 override core function taxonomy_field_validate

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

Due to some custom modifications in the hierarchical_select module I need to be able to override the the taxonomy_field_validate function in the core taxonomy module.

I've tried creating a function in a custom module called MYMODULE_taxonomy_field_validate which it doesn't pick up on and I tried changing the field settings, but that changes how the data is stored in the database and it needs to be kept as a taxonomy term.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to unset this function on form validation.

In your module, write a `hook_form_alter` implementation and write this code inside

```
unset($form['#validate']['taxonomy_field_validate']);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: In some cases you might need to unset validation functions more broadly, like `unset($form['#validate'][0])` it depends on what you have available on your form_alter.